# PHP: How can variables be assigned values from a MySQL Query?

Tags: php

I have a MySQL database, 'fruits', with 10 rows like this:

```
id | variable | value  
1  | apples  | 5  
2  | oranges  | 6
```

How can I efficiently use a query to assign PHP variables values, so I can use them elsewhere:
$apples = 5;
$oranges = 6;

Or to put it another way, assign values to PHP variables based on the 'variables' column in the database.

The only way I can make it work is this:

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql="SELECT variable, value FROM fruits where variable = 'oranges'";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
$row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$oranges = $row["value"];
```

I could do this 10 times but it seems terrible, there must be a better way, presumably involving some sort of loop. Not a professional at this (clearly) so complete code so I can see how it all works would be much appreciated.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You might be looking for [variable variables](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.variable.php), although in almost every scenario, it's better to use an array instead. Have an array, such as `$fruits[$row['variable']] = $row['value'];`, then use `echo $fruits['oranges'];` (be sure to define the array before entering the loop, to avoid *Undefined variable...* notices).

Comment: `extract array_column($row, 'value', 'variable');` but as @Qirel says, better to work with an array instead

Comment: do you know the order of the values in db like apple  then orange then ...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here an example of a Variable-Variable:

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM fruits";
$result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $variable = $row["variable"];
        $$variable = $row["value"];

        echo("Name: " . ${variable} . " Value: " . $$variable . "<br>");
    }
}
```

Best regards

Answer (score 1):

Can use this too.

```
$con = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$sql="SELECT variable, value FROM fruits";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$sql);
while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    ${row["variable"]}= $row["value"];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

I can't see a single reason to do so. 
An array is a variable itself. It's super easy to access any single element with: $rows[2]['variable'] or $rows[1]['value'].

But if you really need some mess you could combine the extract() and a foreach loop.